# PageBlockSection not rendering anything

Tags: rerender

I have written a code to display all the alarms(custom object) associated with an account. The requirement was to have an embedded VF Page so I did it with controller extension. For pagination i have used standard set controller but the buttons in the page are not working.

Can someone help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

There may be other problems with your code, but a definite one I can see is a problem with the `cid` value. You are passing in the value in the Javascript function, but that is not making it to the console call.

You have:

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/cid', true, 'Case');
```

It should probably be:

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/' + cid, true, 'Case');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw but the main problem i'm facing is that the buttons are not working!

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your CommandButtons to CommandLinks. I don't know why, but they seem to work better in cases like this.